# R persp Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r

I am new to R 3D plotting. I basically have a matrix of size 9x3 and each entry of the matrix is a double value:

```
390.7269606 390.7330561 390.412666
296.815086  296.5989998 296.6268851
288.4770256 288.3036607 288.3418227
287.4134039 287.2562576 287.3429308
287.0195664 286.8701923 286.9848413
286.832489  286.6888436 286.814465
286.8124387 286.6696583 286.8013845
286.8062249 286.6645971 286.7765071
286.7860349 286.6451203 286.7765071
284.8167037 284.6893261 284.7967308
```

here what I have to plot them:

```
###loads the above matrix
d2 <- read.csv("data.csv", header=T, dec=".",sep = " ")
###loads x,y,z
x <- c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
y <- c(3,4,10)
z <- d2
###supposed to draw it!
persp(x, y, z,
  zlab="Score", ylab = "C", xlab="T",
  theta=30, phi=15,ticktype='detailed',
  col="springgreen", shade=0.5)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in persp.default(x, y, z, zlab = "Score", ylab = "C",  : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
Calls: persp -> persp.default
Execution halted
```

It has something to do with the double values in z matrix, but I don't understand why it is an issue and how to solve it.

Help!

Comment: I guess you need to convert to `matrix`.  Right now it is a `data.frame`

Comment: aha you are right as.matrix fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'z' should be a `matrix`

```
 z <- as.matrix(d2)
```

and then it should run.